# hide the errors but retain the validation summary header of ASP.NET Validation summary

Tags: asp.net, css

I try to solve this issue by creating a css and apply it on Validation Summary. The solution below only works on Firefox and Google Chrome but not working in IE(7,8, and 9). Anyone experienced this before?

Here is my solution

```
1st solution:

<style type="text/css">
    .validation_summary_as_bulletlist ul
    {
        display: none;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
</style>

2nd solution

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#<%=valSummary.ClientID%>').css('display', 'none');
         $('#<%=valSummary.ClientID%>').css('visibility', 'hidden');

        })
    </script>

 <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSummary" ValidationGroup="moneyValidation" runat="server"
                            ShowSummary="true" CssClass="validation_summary_as_bulletlist" HeaderText="Currency is Required"
                            DisplayMode="BulletList" />
```

I don't know what is wrong with the codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use jquery to hide contents. Then You do not have to think how should it work in particular browsers:

```
$('#<%=valSummary.ClientID%>').hide();
```

Comment: I tried this one but it's not working <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%=valSummary.ClientID%>').hide();
    });
    </script>

Comment: Have you checked if all the code is properly generated (IE->View Source) and is running at all?